# Cannot directly transfer files beetween 2 or more android devices using LinuxMint

Tags: linux-mint, android, file-transfer

I have LinuxMint on my PC, I plugged in 2 android phones in the USB slots and when I try to copy/move files 'into' the device SD card it shows,

> Error while copying "File_name".

[image]

But it works if I copy files from my PC, so I have to copy file from one device to PC the copy the file from my PC to other device.

Please explain how to fix this.